# Auth0: Sign Up - Changing the flow

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0

We have integrated Auth0 with our "User Portal" app. This integration is working fine."User Portal" has its own "sign up" funcnatility(existing). Please refer the following illustration to understand our requirement.
1: User Starts the "User Portal" application.
2: Auth0 login screen gets displayed.
3: User clicks the "sign up" link on the log-in screen.
4: User is re-directed to a page on the "User Portal" app ( so that existing "Create Account" flow continues).

In a nutshell, we want to use our existing "sign up" functionality (this would need some tweak like we will use user managemnt API to create user account on Auth0) so that user does not go through change in user experience (we want to minimize the same).

Any pointers would be helpeful. We are trying all options, we have at this point in time.

best regards